# Best Proposal Distribution for asymmetric target in Metropolis Hastings (Exponential Target)

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Suppose I know my target distribution is asymmetric, for instance, suppose my target distribution is an exponential
$$
p(x) = e^{-x} \qquad\qquad x\in [0, +\infty)
$$

[image: Exponential Distribution]

Is there any theory regarding what kind of proposal distributions would perform best? The simplest choice would be a symmetric proposal as per Random Walk Metropolis. However, it is not obvious to me that this woud be a good choice for this kind of distribution. Indeed I think a symmetic proposal would probably be the worst choice because it would be very dependent on the scaling! Maybe an asymmetric proposal would be best? For instance an exponential? In which case it would not simplify in the MH ratio.

Comment: The optimal proposal is the Exponential distribution itself.

Comment: @Xi’an Even when the target distribution is some other asymmetric distribution? Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: No no my answer was addressing the case of the exponential target. And pointing out that optimality cannot really be well defined in this setting.

Comment: @Xi’an okay! Even though optimality cannot be well defined do you know of any research around MH with asymmetrical targets?

Comment: I do not know of a specific paper on the topic. On principle, a reparameterisation can reduce the assymmetry. And using a Langevin algorithm should help with the assymmetry since the gradient will be steeper in some parts.

Comment: Not necessarily the best, but you may be interested in the slice sampler. It's a pretty robust "off-the-shelf" sampler.